# How to export several functions from a jsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to have some reusable JS code in `client.jsx` file that is imported to React components (built with webpack).
you can see `save()`, `saveWithTwoCallbacks()`, `saveWithCallback()` methods in this `client.jsx` are mostly copy-pasted. what would be the right JS syntax for `save()` methods to reuse each other?

client.jsx file:

```
import {browserHistory} from "react-router";

module.exports = {

    saveWithTwoCallbacks: function (urlToCall, objectToSave, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlToCall,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(objectToSave),
            success: function () {
                successCallback();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                errorCallback(err.toString());
            }
        });
    },

    saveWithCallback: function (urlToCall, objectToSave, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlToCall,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(objectToSave),
            success: function () {
                callback();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(xhr, status, err.toString());
            }
        });
    },

    save: function (urlToCall, objectToSave, navigateTo) {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlToCall,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(objectToSave),
            success: function () {
                // console.log("saved")
                browserHistory.push(navigateTo)
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(xhr, status, err.toString());
            }
        });
    },

}
```

LoginComponent.jsx file:

```
import React from "react";
import {saveWithTwoCallbacks} from "./client";

class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data : {
        },
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
handleChange(e) {
    setFormChangeToStateData(e, this)
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    saveWithTwoCallbacks("http://localhost:9000/login", this.state.data, onSuccess, onError);
}

render()......
}
export default LoginComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what would be the right JS syntax for save() methods to reuse each other?

Nothing special. Function definitions are done via `function f() { ... }` and function calls via `f()`.

In your case, you put the `$.ajax` call in `saveWithTwoCallbacks` and then just call the right function from inside the others.

To make this easier, use [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_named_exports):

```
export function saveWithTwoCallbacks(urlToCall, objectToSave, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  // $.ajax ...
}

export function saveWithCallback(urlToCall, objectToSave, callback) {
  saveWithTwoCallbacks(
    urlToCall,
    objectToSave,
    callback,
    (xhr, status, err) => console.error(xhr, status, err.toString())
  );
}

export function save(urlToCall, objectToSave, navigateTo) {
  saveWithCallback(urlToCall, objectToSave, () => browserHistory.push(navigateTo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would only use one function

```
saveWithTwoCallbacks: function (urlToCall, objectToSave, successCallback, successCallbackParams, errorCallback, errorCallbackParams) {
    $.ajax({
        url: urlToCall,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(objectToSave),
        success: function () {
            successCallback.apply(null, successCallbackParams);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            errorCallback.apply(null, errorCallbackParams);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not just `success: successCallback` and `error: errorCallback` ?

Comment: To pass additional parameters to those functions ... if you want to :)

Comment: But that can easily be done by the caller: `saveWithTwoCallbacks(.., ..., function() { something(foo, bar); })`.

Comment: Yea both do the same - just a matter of preference I think.